# Changing a single UIButton image in a collection view is affecting multiple cells

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I currently am using a Collection View to display a list of events to a user, and each one of my custom cells has a button that invites the user to attend the event. When pressed, the button image should then change to a newImage.png which displays that they are now attending that event. When I do this in my code below, pressing the button does in fact change the picture, but as I scroll down my collection view, **multiple cells that have yet to be clicked also have changed to the "newImage.png."** How can I stop this from happening?

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell{

 @IBAction func myButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "newImage.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

 @IBOutlet weak var myButtonOutlet: UIButton!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up solving my problem. I have an array that I store my Cells in. Each cell has a boolean called `isAttending`. In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I implemented the code below along with the function `switchImage`:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CalendarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CalendarCell

    cell.customButton.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
    cell.customButton.addTarget(self, action: "switchImage:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}



  func switchImage(sender: UIButton){
    let index : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
    if (events[index].isAttending == false){
      events[index].isAttending = true
      cell.customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "isAttending.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   }else{
      events[index].isAttending = false
      cell.customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "isNotAttending.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The collection view is reusing cells, as it is designed to do. What you should do is reset the image in your cellForItemAtIndexPath implementation.

Comment: Would this involve moving the outlet for the button into my CollectionViewClass? And then how do I communicate that the button was pressed on a particular cell?

Comment: Why do you need a button inside your cell? Can't you just implement collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath instead?

Comment: Currently my didSelectItemAtIndexPath performs a seque to a more detailed looked at the event. The button is supposed to be a quick way to attend the event without moving to the other view controller.

Comment: Gotcha. Why not create a custom cell with an embedded button, and make each cell call back to your class when its button is tapped? That way cells are responsible for managing their own buttons, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by embedded button?

Comment: A button as a subview of your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before too and this is most likely do to cell reuse. What you might try to do to avoid this problem is to explicitly set the cell's image in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath()` and then add something to your model that keeps track of which events the user is attending. Then, again in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath()`, check the model to see what button should be on that cell, and then change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store selected button index in your class and check perticular index in your function

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
     myButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "newImage.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

  //change background image here also your button code
}
return cell
}
```

and after doing this steps . Reload collection view  .